# How to ADD data from CRUD ajax in php codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, crud

I want to add update and delete data in the table below. Delete is working. But I have a problem adding data using CRUD
[image]

Here is the controller. I add data into two join tables, parent and student using a single form on one button click.

```
    public function register_students()
{

    // $this->load->model('Register_model','multi_model',TRUE);
    $encrypted_password1 = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('p_pwd'));

    $parent_data = array(

        'parent_code' => $this->input->post('parent_code'),
        'f_name' => $this->input->post('p_first_name'),
        'l_name' => $this->input->post('p_last_name'),
        'DOB' => $this->input->post('p_dob'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('p_address'),
        'tel' => $this->input->post('p_tel_no'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('p_username'),
        'password' => $encrypted_password1,
    );



     $id = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('parent',$parent_data);




    $encrypted_password = $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('pwd'));
    $student_data = array(
        's_id' => '',
        'student_code' => $this->input->post('student_code'),
        'f_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'l_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'DOB' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'tel' => $this->input->post('tel_no'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $encrypted_password,
        'p_id' => $id


    );
    $insert = $this->Model_Action->insertTable('student',$student_data);

    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));

    redirect('student');


}
```

Here is my model

```
 function insertTable($table, $data) {
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

This is my view - javascript section.  I have removed edit function and delete function in this section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#student_table').DataTable();
  } );
    var save_method; 
    var table;



function add_book()
{
  save_method = 'add';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); 
  $('#modal_form').modal('show'); 
}


function save()
{
  var url;
  if(save_method == 'add')
  {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('/Student/register_students')?>";
  }
  else
  {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('/Student/student_update')?>";
  }

   // ajax adding data to database
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           //if success close modal and reload ajax table
           $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
          location.reload();// for reload a page
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}
```

I have used bootstrap model for adding and updating forms and those are also working fine.

Comment: did you check if you get any $data? Did you check, if the database columns match the $data array keys? AND what does your browser console say?

Comment: yeah, because I tried adding data without ajax, (using form action method) and It did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you are using **redirect('student');** on ajax call. Dot do it if you want work with ajax. I advise you:

```
$array = array(
    'link' => 'strudent',
    'status' => true
);

echo json_encode($array);
return;
```

And on ajax success:

```
window.location.href = data.link;
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I can update However I have to reload the page. and when I click the 'save' button it shows that error 'error adding/ updating data'  But the data get updated.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, I hope you would help me solve this as well. :)

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with url which you call ajax??

Comment: Thank you I found the error, I have only taken one table data for ajax table view.  So I wrote a join query. now it's all working. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad to help :)